# SQLITE Insert Multiple Rows Using Select as Value

Tags: sqlite, insert, rows

I have a sqlite statement that will only insert one row.

```
INSERT INTO queue (TransKey, CreateDateTime, Transmitted) 
VALUES (
  (SELECT Id from trans WHERE Id != (SELECT TransKey from queue)),
   '2013-12-19T19:47:33',
   0
)
```

How would I have it insert every row where Id from trans != (SELECT TransKey from queue) in one statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO queue (TransKey, CreateDateTime, Transmitted) 
  SELECT Id, '2013-12-19T19:47:33',  0 
  FROM trans WHERE Id != (SELECT TransKey from queue)
```

There are two different "flavors" of `INSERT`.  The one you're using (`VALUES`) inserts one or more rows that you "create" in the `INSERT` statement itself.  The other flavor (`SELECT`) inserts a variable number of rows that are retrieved from one or more other tables in the database.

While it's not immediately obvious, the `SELECT` version allows you to include expressions and simple constants -- as long as the number of columns lines up with the number of columns you're inserting, the statement will work (in other databases, the *types* of the values must match the column types as well).